# How does the embryo inside a shelled egg get oxygen?

Tags: breathing, eggs

If I'm not mistaken a typical animal in the womb will get oxygen via the umbilical cord from the mother. Thus allowing it to "breathe" in a liquid environment. I thought maybe shells are permeable and allow air to come in through the shell, but then I thought of eggs laid in the ground like turtles do.

- How do animals in soft/hard shells get their oxygen?

Comment: Both forms are ultimately by diffusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point in both cases is that the eggshell and membrane are permeable to oxygen, as you thought. There are subtleties - for instance, the oxygen-permeability of avian (hard-shelled) eggshells [changes during development](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/978168).

In the case of eggs laid underground, as in sea turtle eggs, the leathery shell is still permeable to oxygen. The sand restricts oxygen flow, but turtles [seem to take care to not bury their eggs too deep for oxygen to diffuse to their developing nest](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/918411).