# How does a turtle develop inside its egg?

Tags: biochemistry, development, herpetology, eggs

This is related to [Cause of premature death in turtle eggs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107495/cause-of-premature-death-in-turtle-eggs), for those interested.

I have noticed that *Kinosternon spp.* eggs have three layers:

- hard outer shell
- white opaque membrane (like the one you see in hard-boiled eggs)
- transparent memebrane that completely wraps the baby turtle

Since I am forced to manually open this species' eggs (see the linked question for details), but doing so too early will likely result in the death of the developing turtle, I would like to know more about how turtles develop inside the egg (from a physical/chemical point of view).

I am assuming [turtle eggs are permeable to oxygen](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/how-does-the-embryo-inside-a-shelled-egg-get-oxygen/37449#37449).

1. assuming lack of oxygen is the root cause of these deaths, which, out of the three membranes, is more or less permeable to oxygen (in other terms: would breaking just one or two of the egg's layers be enough to let the turtle breathe?)
2. when do turtles start to breathe with their lungs?
3. Would it be harmful for the egg to get oxygen too early?
4. why would a turtle possibly die in the egg if it is opened too early? Could it be because of bacterial infections of some sort? I know for a fact that some breeders hatch turtles with shell-less incubation, the same tecnique used for chickens.

Biology is not really my area of expertise, I am just a passionate turtle breeder and I have not been able to find anything relevant that could shed some light on this issue.
My idea is to get some scientific insights that could possibly lead to a change in the incubation's parameters.
So any help would be greatly appreciated.